# how to parse json object inside json object in java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to parse below JSON and looking for "zip-code" value "526262". I'm new to Java and struggling to get the zip-code value?

This is my JSON:

```
{
    "id": "6fffdfdf-8d04-4f4e-b746-20930671bd9c",
    "timestamp": "2017-07-21T03:51:27.329Z",
    "lang": "en",
    "result": {
        "source": "testsrc",
        "resolvedQuery": "testquery",
        "action": "test",
        "actionIncomplete": true,
        "parameters": {
            "zip-code": "526262"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my Java code:

```
       String test= "{\n" +
            "\t\"id\": \"6fffdfdf-8d04-4f4e-b746-20930671bd9c\",\n" +
            "\t\"timestamp\": \"2017-07-21T03:51:27.329Z\",\n" +
            "\t\"lang\": \"en\",\n" +
            "\t\"result\": {\n" +
            "\t\t\"source\": \"testsrc\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"resolvedQuery\": \"testquery\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"action\": \"test\",\n" +
            "\t\t\"actionIncomplete\": true,\n" +
            "\t\t\"parameters\": {\n" +
            "\t\t\t\"zip-code\": \"526262\"\n" +
            "\t\t}\n" +
            "\t}\n" +
            "}";

JSONObject request = new JSONObject(test);
String zipCode = request.getJSONObject("result").get("parameters").toString();
System.out.println("zipCode is : " + zipCode);
```

But I'm getting below output:

```
zipCode is : {"zip-code":"526262"}
```

How to get zip-code value alone?

Can someone help how to get this value in java?

Comment: String zipCode = request.getJSONObject("result").get("parameters").get("zip-code").toString(); ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use getJSONObject when getting `parameters` so that you can keep using the JSONObject API to dig deeper.

```
request.getJSONObject("result").getJSONObject("parameters").getString("zip-code");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getJSONObject("result").get("parameters").getString("zip_code")
```

will solve your problem. JSON objects are built to handle nesting.